# How to abstract and export multiple table data in a single excel file?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jexcelapi

I am generating an Excel file with [JExcel](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) and trying to display multiple table values.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/resilenceCenterExcel", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void defaultPageExce654(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
    OutputStream out = null;
    try
    {
        List<ResilenceCenter> resilence=resilenceCenterService.doGetAllResilenceCenter();
     response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");

     SimpleDateFormat st = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");

     response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", 
    "attachment; filename=ResilenceCenterExcel.xls");

     WritableWorkbook w = Workbook.createWorkbook(response.getOutputStream());
     WritableSheet s = w.createSheet("Demo", 0);

     s.addCell(new Label(0, 0, "CCC ID"));
     s.addCell(new Label(1, 0, "Source of reporting"));


     s.addCell(new Label(2, 0, "Butterflies ID"));
     s.addCell(new Label(3, 0, "Reported by"));
     s.addCell(new Label(4, 0, "Area of intervention"));
     s.addCell(new Label(5, 0, "Case Category"));
     s.addCell(new Label(6, 0, "Child located"));
     s.addCell(new Label(7, 0, "Any kind of official document available"));
     s.addCell(new Label(8, 0, "Name of the Child"));
     s.addCell(new Label(9, 0, "Sex of the Child"));
     s.addCell(new Label(10, 0, "Father/ Mother Name"));

     s.addCell(new Label(11, 0, "Local/ present address of the Child"));
     s.addCell(new Label(12, 0, "Permanent address"));
     s.addCell(new Label(13, 0, "DD entry done"));

     s.addCell(new Label(14, 0, "DD No"));
     s.addCell(new Label(15, 0, "DD Police Station Name"));
     s.addCell(new Label(16, 0, "FIR lodged"));

     s.addCell(new Label(17, 0, "FIR no"));
     s.addCell(new Label(18, 0, "FIR Police Station Name"));
     s.addCell(new Label(19, 0, "Child produced before the CWC"));
     s.addCell(new Label(20, 0, "CWC ID"));
     s.addCell(new Label(21, 0, "Provided shelter in resilience centre"));
     s.addCell(new Label(22, 0, "track the missing child ID"));

     s.addCell(new Label(23, 0, "Duration of stay"));
     s.addCell(new Label(24, 0, "Reasons for leaving"));
     s.addCell(new Label(25, 0, "Status"));
     s.addCell(new Label(26, 0, "Assistance provided"));
     s.addCell(new Label(27, 0, "Closing comments"));


     int i=1;
     for(ResilenceCenter resilenceCenter:resilence){
         s.addCell(new Label(0, i, resilenceCenter.getCccId()));
         s.addCell(new Label(1, i, resilenceCenter.getSourceOfReportingCccId()));
         s.addCell(new Label(2, i, resilenceCenter.getBtfId()));
         s.addCell(new Label(3, i, resilenceCenter.getReportedBy()));
         s.addCell(new Label(4, i, resilenceCenter.getAreaOfIntervention()));
         s.addCell(new Label(5, i, resilenceCenter.getCaseCategory()));
         s.addCell(new Label(6, i, resilenceCenter.getChildLocated()));
         s.addCell(new Label(7, i, resilenceCenter.getDocumentAvailable()));
         s.addCell(new Label(8, i, resilenceCenter.getChildName()));
         s.addCell(new Label(9, i, resilenceCenter.getChildSex()));
         s.addCell(new Label(10, i, resilenceCenter.getFatherMotherName()));
         s.addCell(new Label(11, i, resilenceCenter.getLocalAddress()));
         s.addCell(new Label(12, i, resilenceCenter.getPermanentAddress()));
         s.addCell(new Label(13, i, resilenceCenter.getDdEntry()));
         s.addCell(new Label(14, i, resilenceCenter.getDdNo()));
         s.addCell(new Label(15, i, resilenceCenter.getDdPoliceStation()));
         s.addCell(new Label(16, i, resilenceCenter.getFirLodged()));
         s.addCell(new Label(17, i, resilenceCenter.getSectionFir()));
         s.addCell(new Label(18, i, resilenceCenter.getFirPoliceStation()));
         s.addCell(new Label(19, i, resilenceCenter.getChildCwc()));
         s.addCell(new Label(20, i, resilenceCenter.getCwcId()));
         s.addCell(new Label(21, i, resilenceCenter.getShelter()));
         s.addCell(new Label(22, i, resilenceCenter.getTrackMissingChildId()));
         s.addCell(new Label(23, i, resilenceCenter.getDurationOfStay()));
         s.addCell(new Label(24, i, resilenceCenter.getReasonsForLeaving()));
         s.addCell(new Label(25, i, resilenceCenter.getStatus()));
         s.addCell(new Label(26, i, resilenceCenter.getAssistanceProvided()));
         s.addCell(new Label(27, i, resilenceCenter.getClosingComment()));

         i++;
     }
     w.write();
     w.close();

    } catch (Exception e)
    {
     e.printStackTrace();
    } finally
    {
     if (out != null)
         try{
      out.close();
         }catch(Exception e){

         }
    }

}
```

Comment: Pls elaborate. Currently I'm at loss to understand what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: need to export multiple tables data in excel file

Comment: (technologies used spring,mysql,java,jsp)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why do not you add multiple worksheets to your workbook and place the results on those worksheets?